# xbuild with [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(string,string) parameters doesn't work properly (MSBuild is fine)

Tags: regex, linux, msbuild, mono, xbuild

I have a target that reads a .proj file with ReadLinesFromFile and then try to match a version number (e.g. 1.0.23) from the contained lines like:

```
<Target Name="GetRevision">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(MyDir)GetStuff.Data.proj">
      <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="GetStuffLines" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <In>@(GetStuffLines)</In>
      <Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), "(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)"))</Out>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="Revision number [$(Out)]" />
    <CreateProperty Value="$(Out)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="RevisionNumber" />
    </CreateProperty>
  </Target>
```

The result is always empty.. Even if I try to do a simple Match($(In), "somestring") its not working correctly in linux/xbuild. This **does work** on windows/msbuild

Any tricks/ideas? An alternative would be to get the property version out of the first .proj file, instead of reading all lines and matching the number with a regex, but I don't even know if that is possible.

I am running versions:

```
XBuild Engine Version 12.0
Mono, Version 4.2.1.0
```

**EDIT:**
I've been able to trace it further down into the parameters that go into Match(), there is something wrong with the variables evaluation. The function actually works with for example `Match("foobar","bar")` I will get `bar`

But weird things happen with other inputs, e.g. `Match($(In), "Get")` will match `Get` because it is actually matching against the string "@(GetStuffLines)"

When I do `Match($(In), "@..")` I will get a match of `@(G`

But then, when I do `Match($(In), "@.*")` I actually get the entire content of the input file `GetStuff.Data.proj` which indicates that the variable was correctly expanded somewhere and the matching matched the entire input string.

Comment: Does it support regex at all? If yes, but there are issues with ``\``, try `"([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)"`.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't, any string I put in there is not matched.. Even though I think yesterday I was able to match something but not sure. I didn't find anything regarding regex support in xbuild :s I have, e.g. ```$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)'))``` that work just fine.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify that you actually need the value? `<Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), "([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)")).Value</Out>`?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work (it does in msbuild but the .Value needs to be inside the last parenthesis). Now I am pretty sure this functionality is broken, I tried it with ```<Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match("foobar", "bar"))</Out>``` and still nothing is stored in $(Out)

Comment: EDIT: I made a mistake when trying the foobar/bar approach, I was running towards a different target.. that regex does indeed work with xbuild

Comment: If it does, perhaps, the xbuild uses POSIX BRE. Try `"[[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+"`. Or `"\([0-9]\+\)[.]\([0-9]\+\)[.]\([0-9]\+\)"`.

Comment: I got closer to the problem now.. its the input parameter, its not working with a variable, but works with a string, i.e. ```<Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match("asd1.0.59asd", "([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)").Value)</Out>``` **works**

Comment: Well, it looks like a bug.

Comment: This is getting more eerie than I expected. I will try to update the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to circumvent Match() because it seems to be bugged at this point.
The ugly solution I came up with was to use Exec and grep the pattern like:

```
 <Exec Command="grep -o -P '[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+' $(MyDir)GetStuff.Data.proj > extractedRevisionNumber.tmp" Condition="$(OSTYPE.Contains('linux'))"/>
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(ComponentRootDir)extractedRevisionNumber.tmp" Condition="$(OSTYPE.Contains('linux'))">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="GetExtractedRevisionNumber" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
```

I couldn't even use the properties `ConsoleToMSBuild` and `ConsoleOutput` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124731%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) because xbuild didn't recognize those.. That's why I grep the pattern and save it into a temp file which can be read with `ReadLinesFromFile` into the `ItemName="GetExtractedRevisionNumber"` that I use later.